# What is the relationship between AppScript oauth scopes and linked gcp project's scopes?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-cloud-platform

I have one question about gcp. Maybe i missed some details from the documentation, if it's the case - sorry) So, i have appscript and i wanted to stream its logs to GCP, so i created GCP project and set project number to appscript.

It works fine, but here is confusing part - appscript has list of oauth scopes required for script execution and oauth scopes can be set also to the linked GCP project.

AppScript properties:
[image]
GCP project properties:
[image]

So, my question - are those oauth scopes from the gcp project affect appscript permissions? According to my understanding and testing they are completely separate from each other, but i missed detailed explanation from the docs regarding this moment. Could someone for example add some scope to gcp project and it will implicitly affect appscript execution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### About Apps Script project and OAuth consent screen scopes

- The scopes in your Apps Script project are the ones your code needs to work correctly
- You can either [set them manually](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/concepts/scopes#setting_explicit_scopes) in the script manifest or let Apps Script determine and add the needed scopes automatically (you will be ask to authorize them when you run a function after adding code blocks that require additonal scopes)
- When it comes to the [OAuth screen scopes](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/10311615?hl=en) in your GCP project - you only need to set them if you plan to publish your script as a [public app / Addon](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/how-tos/publish-add-on-overview) that other users can install and use
- If you use your GCP project only for private pruposes - e.g. viewing logs, you do not need to do anything about the scopes in the OAuth screen and can disregard the points below
- If you do want to [publish a public Addon](https://developers.google.com/workspace/marketplace/how-to-publish) - you do need to  [configure the OAuth consent screen](https://developers.google.com/workspace/marketplace/configure-oauth-consent-screen), which means adding there all the scopes your script needs and submit them for verification
- If the latter applies, you need to provide a justification for why and how you are going to use each single scope in case the scope is a sensitive one, and if a scope is a [restricted](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/9110914?hl=en#restricted-scopes) one - you will need to undergo a pricey [Security assessment](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/9110914?hl=en#restricted-scopes&zippy=%2Csecurity-assessment)
- To avoid unnecessary hassle / costs with the scope verification, try to use as limited scopes as possible
- For example, if Apps Script automatically awarded the script the scope
  https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive - see if a https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly or a https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file scope would be enough for your purposes and change it in the manifest manually